# Error: Wrong number of arguments to call the procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

Procedure is:

**PERSON_Q(STATUS IN STATUS_OBJ, COMM OUT VARCHAR2)**

**create or replace TYPE STATUS_OBJ AS OBJECT
(
ID NUMBER,
MESSAGE VARCHAR2(255),
STATE NUMBER,
NAME VARCHAR2(1000)
);**

My java code is:

```
public void update() {
OracleCallableStatement os = null;
Connection conn = null;
Object[] obj = new Object[4];
try {
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pwd);
obj[0]=2;
obj[1]="status";
obj[2]=2;
obj[3]="name";
os = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("call PERSON_Q(?,?)");
StructDescriptor sd = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("STATUS_OBJ", conn);
os.setObject(1, new STRUCT(sd, conn, obj));
os.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, "COMM");
int response = os.executeUpdate();
} catch(){SQLException e}
}
```

Exception:

> {ORA-06553: PLS-306: WRONG NUMBER OR TYPES OF ARGUMENTS IN CALL TO
> "PERSON_Q"}

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem.  Your code ran successfully for me.  The only thing I can suggest is to delete the parameter `COMM` from your `registerOutParameter()` call: that parameter might end being interpreted as the type of the stored procedure's `OUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SP has only one IN parameter but in your code you are trying to pass in two parameters:

```
call PERSON_Q(?,?)
```

Comment: If the procedure is declared with two parameters - regardless of whether they are IN or OUT parameters - this would be the expected call format.